# Fast, scalable hash lookup database? (Berkeley'ish)

Tags: hashmap, berkeley-db, memcachedb

I use and love Berkeley but it seems to bog down once you get near a million or so entries, especially on the inserts.  I've tried memcachedb which works but it's not being maintained so I'm worried of using it in production.  Does anyone have any other similar solutions, basically I want to be able to do key lookups on a large(possibly distributed) dataset(40+ million).

Note: Anything NOT in Java is a bonus. :-) It seems most things today are going the Java route.

Comment: The last commit on memcachedb was April 14, 09.  That's really not too long ago for stable open source project:  http://code.google.com/p/memcachedb/source/list

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Project Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/)?

Comment: Looks like an interest project.

Comment: Hmm, never heard of that.  Any idea what they use for the database part?  There is not a whole lot of info on it so it's hard to judge against other solutions.

Comment: From the configuration page:

persistence— The persistence backend used by the store. Currently this could be one of bdb, mysql, memory, readonly, and cache. The difference between cache and memory is that memory will throw and OutOfMemory exception if it grows larger than the JVM heap whereas cache will discard data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you had a look at:

[Metabrew key-value store blog post](http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores/)

There is a big list of key-value stores with a little bit of discussion in each of them. If you still have doubts you could join the so called [Nosql](http://groups.google.com/group/nosql-discussion) google group and ask for help there.

Answer (score 1):

[Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) is insanely fast and actively developed. It is written in C(no java). Compiles out of the box on POSIX OS(no dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the hash backend? That should be faster for insert and key search.

Comment: What do you mean by a hash backend? Anything in specific?